# Winston MongoDB - Authentication error when passing the database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, winston

I'm opening this issue because I'm not sure if this only happens to me.

I'm having trouble connecting to the database when in the mongo url I pass the database. I'm using a structure similar to this:

```
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  levels: customLevels,
  format: winston.format.combine(
    winston.format.errors({ stack: true }),
    winston.format.json(),
    winston.format.timestamp(),
  ),
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.MongoDB({
      db: `mongodb://user:pass@host:port/database`,
      tryReconnect: true,
      collection: 'logs',
      options: { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }
    }),
  ],
});
```

But when trying to connect, I get the following error:

```
winston-mongodb: will try reconnecting in 10 seconds
winston-mongodb: error initialising logger MongoError: Authentication failed.
```

When I remove the database from the connection string from mongodb it connects and creates a database called "test" on mongo. The username and password are correct, as I entered the same data to create the database I am trying to connect.

Anyone else going through something similar?

Comment: Does the database "database" exists and has that user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably you will need to add the authentication database in your uri as follow:

```
 db: `mongodb://user:pass@host:port/database?authSource=admin`
```

Otherways mongo will search the user in your provided "database" ...

Comment: This also applies to MongoKitten and Fluent's Mongo Driver.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to add a database on winston logging

```
new transports.MongoDB({
  db:"mongodb_database_url",
  options: {
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  }
})
```

you can obtain the database URL by going to MongoDB cloud, selecting your cluster and clicking on connect option. Then choose connect your application and you can find your MongoDB database URL there.